# Can't iterate over an array stored in Smart Pointers

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Suppose i have the following piece of code:

```
std::shared_ptr<char*> getString()
{
  char hello[] = {'h','e','l','l','o'};

  return std::make_shared<char*>(hello);

}   

int main()
{

    std::shared_ptr<char*> shared_str = getString();
    std::cout<< (*shared_str)<<std::endl;//OK
    std::cout<<(*shared_str)<<std::endl;//KO


  return 0;
}
```

I don't know why I get just the first printing, while the second is in error. For the same reason I cannot iterate over such smart pointers like  the following :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
std::cout<<(*shared_str)[i];
```

because also in this case, just the letter 'h' would be printed.
I am really confused about smart pointers and i didn't find that much since most of the explenations are about the handling of the life-time of referenced objects.

To summarize : error happens because the "hello" array goes out of scope, in fact, make_shared allocates memory dynamically  for a char*, and stores inside the pointer "hello",however the array itself is going to die as the function geString() ends.

Comment: You can't have shared pointers to local variables. The thing that `shared_ptr` manages must be allocated with `new`.

Comment: " don't know why I get just the first printing, while the second is in error" ... arent they exactly the same ? `std::cout<< (*shared_str)<<std::endl;//OK` and `std::cout<<(*shared_str)<<std::endl;//KO` the only difference i see is a space and the comment....

Comment: Undefined behaviour is like that.   It can seem to work sometimes, and obviously fail other times.   The point is - any behaviour is permitted, including behaviour that varies if the code is executed more than once.

Comment: @tobi303 They are; that’s what the question is about. The reason the first works but later ones don’t is that it’s undefined behavior. Neither is guaranteed to work and it’s just luck that the first does.

Comment: @DanielH yes in the meantime I got it. When i first read "second is in error" i though this is refering to a compiler error and got confused

Answer (score 3):

You have undefined behaviour in your code. This line:

```
return std::make_shared<char*>(hello);
```

assign hello to the shared pointer which you are returning, but this is a local array which does not exist after returning. <strike>Also shared_ptr will delete this pointer once its reference count reaches zero which is another UB.</strike>

The easiest solution is to use std::string:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::string> getString()
{
  char hello[] = {'h','e','l','l','o', '\0'};
  return std::make_shared<std::string>(hello);
}
```

Comment: Still UB: `hello` is not nul-terminated, so constructing an `std::string` with the `char*` constructor will read past the end.

Comment: Why not just `return std::make_shared<std::string>("hello");`?

Comment: Why not simply `return std::make_shared<std::string>("hello");`?

Comment: Technically, there's no UB when the `shared_ptr` ref-count reaches 0. What OP's code is doing is creating a smart pointer to a pointer: In other words, a `char *` is allocated and stored in the `shared_ptr` as a `char **`, storing a copy of the pointer that was fed to it. It's dereferenced and used as a `char *`, and then at the end of the program, the `char*` is `delete`d. So the UB you're describing (`delete`ing a local variable) doesn't actually happen. The other UB you described in your post is correct, though.

Comment: make_shared<> uses ::new to allocate memory, then the "hello" array is dynamically allocated. make_shared returns a shared_ptr that is returned by copy, the counter should never go to zero!

Comment: @AndreaLoforte `then the "hello" array is dynamically allocated. ` is it? make_shared allocates memory for type char** as Xirema has pointed out above, then assigns to it (after dereferencing) a value of `hello` .

Comment: @AndreaLoforte: _"then the "hello" array is dynamically allocated."_ No it isn't. Remember, a `char*` is just a pointer, not an owning container.